# Could not locate LayerGroup in catalog GeoServer + OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, angular

I have a Layer Group in GeoServer which contains 4 regular layers (layers and group belonging to "TRAC" workspace). I'm trying to do the following on map clicking:

```js
featureRequestGS = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:25830',
  featurePrefix: 'TRAC',
  featureTypes: ['groupLayer'],
  outputFormat: 'application/json',
  filter: containsFilter('geom', clickPoint, 'EPSG:25830'),
});
```

Once I make the request to GeoServer, I get that **GeoServer couldn't locate groupLayer in catalog**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">
<ows:ExceptionText>Could not locate {trac}groupLayer in catalog.</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

The funny thing is that on map initialization I set an WMS layer with the GeoServer layer group and it works fine:

```js
this.groupLayer =
new ImageLayer({
  source: new ImageWMS({
    url: environment.baseUrl,
    params: {LAYERS: 'groupLayer'},
    projection: proyeccion
  })
});

this.map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [this.groupLayer],
  view: new View({
    projection: proyeccion
  })
});
```

Any idea of what am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty stuck with this!

P.D: This is the `GetFeature` request body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetFeature xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" outputFormat="application/json" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
   <Query typeName="TRAC:groupLayer" srsName="EPSG:25830">
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
         <Contains>
            <PropertyName>geom</PropertyName>
            <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:25830">
               <pos srsDimension="2">60000 47000</pos>
            </Point>
         </Contains>
      </Filter>
   </Query>
</GetFeature>
```

Comment: Your grouplayer is not in a workspace so you don't need "trac" - I'm not entirely sure you can make a getFeature request against a GroupLayer though as I think they are a WMS only thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea of what am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty stuck with this!

Group layers are a WMS construct, you can't access them through a WFS request.

Comment: Thought it did behave as a normal layer. Thanks!